# Java 8 Optional in entity field

Tags: java, hibernate, java-8, option-type

Can I use Optional in fields of hibernate entity? Maybe with some custom user type?

I know I can use it in methods using `AccesType.FIELD` (I use `AccesType.FIELD` anyway).

Why I want this? Well, I want to stay as far away from nulls as possible.

Answer (score 1):

You should not use `Optional` as a field in a class (either for Hibernate use or not).

As stated by the [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html), it is a value-based class, so not serializable, and use of reference equality (==) and identity hashcode has unpredictable results.

Instead, you can store an instance of the target class (null is ok in relational databases), and return an Optional from accessors (not the getter, which Hibernates expect to return the same class as the field, if I remember well).

Hope this will help.

Comment: What is unpredictable about Optional's equals and hashCode implementations? They seem to have a clear, firm contract in the Javadoc to which you link.

Comment: Sorry for the shortcut. I didn't mean  equals and hashcode, but == and identity hashcode. Thank you for the correction.